# Windows 2003 - Prevent Folder list access but allow file reading

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows, ntfs

i've shared folder.
in this shared folder i have subfolder which i want to prevent users from listing the content.
but i want to allow them write into this folder and also read files if they have full path.

for example : 
\appserver\application    is the main folder (full permission)
\appserver\application\data              is the subfolder, i want to disable file listing.
\appserver\application\data\e354343434.txt         is file into this file folder which i want to allow reading.

any idea?

Thanks,
Omri

Answer (score 2):

The `Bypass Traverse Checking` user right already gives them the ability to do this.

Give them no NTFS permissions on the parent folders. Give them the appropriate NTFS permissions on the subfolders and/or files.

They'll be able to traverse the parent folders, without seeing their contents, and get to the subfolders and/or files by accessing them via the full path.